# ASP Textbox input type date in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I want to use the html5 input type date in my project.

The problem is that i want to get the selected value from the code behind.

I tried the 
but it shows a simple textbox not the HTML5 date control.

When i use the  it's ok but i can't access the control from code behind

thanks

Comment: share your code which you have tried

Comment: need code to help you buddy

Comment: what browser are you using? firefox and ie don't support the html5 date control.

Comment: @bastos.sergio This is was my problem changing to chrome fixed my problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Put runat="server" in the input type tag, in order to access it in the code behind file.